# File hierarchy and local imports

Tags: python-3.x, import, hierarchy

I'm trying to figure out file hierarchy and local imports in python3. I've run into a problem with a file structure below:

```
└── project
    ├── run.py
    └── scripts
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── misc.py
        ├── script1.py
        └── script2.py
```

I use relative imports for all files in the "scripts" directory.

```
from misc import x, y, z
```

I use absolute imports in `run.py`.

```
from scripts.misc import a, b, c
from scripts.script1 import more_stuff
```

My goal is to have the python files independent and fully functional. However, when I attempt to execute `run.py`, I encounter an error.

```
from misc import x, y, z
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'misc'
```

I would expect relative paths to be relative to the original file and not adopt the path of the executed file. Can I fix this by modifying the imports or file structure?

It also appears I don't understand how `__init__.py` works. I want to re-use generic package names (like "scripts"). I had assumed that `__init__.py` files would be read immediately downstream relative to the executed file: if `run.py` is executed, only the scripts directory at the same level should be considered. I have found that a distant (unrelated?) "scripts" directory receives priority. Is this something that can be addressed with more careful absolute paths? Example below.

```
└── dir
    └── project1
    |   ├── run.py
    |   └── scripts
    |       ├── __init__.py
    |       └── settings.py
    └── subdir
        └── project2
            ├── run.py
            └── scripts
                ├── __init__.py
                └── settings.py
```

Executing `run.py` from "project1" will attempt to import the "scripts" directory from project2.

```
cannot import name 'variable' from 'scripts.settings' (/Users/.../dir/subdir/project2/scripts/settings.py)
```

Removing `__init__.py` from project2/scripts no longer produces the error when executing `run.py` from "project1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are saying:

> I use relative imports for all files in the "scripts" directory.
>
> from misc import x, y, z

But this is not relative. For relative you need to have

```
from .misc import x, y, z
```

2. To understand why the unrelated scripts is taking precedence, look on your `sys.path` and verify if indeed it comes before your scripts package. I can assume the is some leftover for ide path manipulation.

Comment: Problem 2 seems to be related to an odd iPython behavior. When I open a new iPython console, the first value in sys.path is replaced with the parent directory of the last executed script. I just tested this by making a new python file in my downloads directory. Now '/Users/username/Downloads' appears at the top of my sys.path in place of '/Users/username/anaconda/bin'. This behavior does not occur via command line when running: `ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`. I can probably write some dirty code to force the correct sys.path value back if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: Problem 1 looks like supplemental modules within a package aren't expected to be run standalone. Using if/else to determine how the imports should be called like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3 should work.

Comment: Additional info on problem 2: Spyder iPython console has options for selecting the current working directory when producing a new console. Was encounter problems due to unawareness of behavior.